# Facebook php sdk for wall post

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I was try many method to post user wall using php sdk.But not success.Anyone know the successfully posting to wall.please help me ... This code return any error but it will not be post user time lime .
currently i was using this php code..

```
  require_once('src/facebook.php');

  $config = array(
'appId' => '#########',
'secret' => '#########################',
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
 $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
 echo $user_id;
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
 if($user_id!=0) 
 {


 try {$attachment =  array(
 'message' => "good Evening",
  'name' => "good Evening",
 'link' => "good Evening",
'description' => "good Evening",
'picture'=>"http://hotactresshotphotos.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/bhama_028.jpg",
'actions' => json_encode(array('name' => $action_name,'link' => $action_link))
      ); 

$result = $facebook->api('/'.$user_id.'/feed', 'post', $attachment);

} 

   catch(FacebookApiException $e) {

    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
                   'scope' => 'publish_stream'
                   )); 
    echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
    error_log($e->getType());
    error_log($e->getMessage());
  }   

  echo '<br /><a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">logout</a>';
} else {


  $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'publish_stream' ) );
  echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

}
```

Answer (score 3):

what is the error exactly you are getting? btw it works for me provided you have publish_stream permission:

```
$attachment =  array(
                 'access_token' => $access_token,
                 'message' => "$message",
                 'name' => "$name",
                 'description' => "$description",
                 'link' => "$link",
                 'picture' => "$pictureUrl",
                 'actions' => array('name'=>'Try it now', 'link' => "$appUrl")
               );

               try{
                  $post_id = $facebook->api("me/feed","POST",$attachment);
               }catch(Exception $e){
                  error_log($e->getMessage());
               }
```

Comment: no error can be return but the content will not be post,also $post_id is null

Comment: please try the piece of code i have posted in answer.

Comment: no ... it will not get any error but not not post the wall

Comment: I copied the your code and is working for me, check if you have correct appId and secret. as well as make sure the variables `$action_link` and `$action_name` are initialised. as I am not seeing the initialisation of these variables in your code snippet.